# Javascript attach event to class name

Tags: javascript

If I have 10 items, with the class name `keyword`:

```
<div class="keyword"></div>
```

How can I attach an event, for example `click`, on this element.

I tried the following, but with no luck: (no alert comes up)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.keyword').onclick = function()
{
    alert(true);
    Search.addKey(this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Requirements:

- Without the onclick attribute
- no jQuery or any other library

Note: the elements are not generated on page load. Their number can be different, each times you click a button for eg.

I need a way to attach to all tags with the class 'keyword' in the 'future'.

Comment: tough, you'll have to do jquery's work.

Comment: For stuff like that jQuery or any other library is exactly what you should consider. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Why reinvent the wheel? How about *why load a large library to perform a fairly simple task*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should delegate the event. Try this:

```
if (document.body.addEventListener)
{
    document.body.addEventListener('click',yourHandler,false);
}
else
{
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick',yourHandler);//for IE
}

function yourHandler(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className.match(/keyword/))
    {
        //an element with the keyword Class was clicked
    }
}
```

You can read more on event delegation on quirksmode.com. AFAIK, this is the best way of achieving what you're trying to achieve. This is how all the major libs (prototype, jQuery, ...) work behind the scenes

***Update***:

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHRqm/), it contains some more explanation. An interesting reference is [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) page. It helped me understand the way IE and W3C events differ and, crucialy, it helped me understand the value, and countless benefits of Event Delegation

Comment: Major libs don't work like this behind the scenes. Where have you seen this?

Comment: It's a nice method, but wouldn't this trigger an event on all elements even if they have no class?

Comment: Erm, in the jquery source, for example. Of course this isn't the actual code, but in essence, this is how they work. check the jquery source!

Comment: @JosephMarikle: the event is always triggered, regardless of there being a specified handler. All this does is "listen" to when these events are triggerd. the only thing you check is if the element that was clicked had a certain class. If so, you can handle the event accordingly. This **is** the most performant approach, honestly

Comment: Nice! I'll have to use it some time.

Comment: Your method works perfectly, but I need to call it N times. If I do so, it calls the onclick function a couple of times, when I click once. How can I clear the functions that are triggered by clicking the element, and defining a new one?

Comment: @Guy David, I'll set up a jsFiddle with an example. Perhaps you can fork it and show me what's going wrong.

Comment: Step 1: I load my web page. Step 2: I click on a class='keyword'. An alert comes up. Step 3: I generate new divs with the class='keyword', and attach the event to all divs. Step 4: I click the elements again, the alert pops twice.

Comment: What I need is a method to clear all the events from the class='keyword'

Comment: Ow, now I see: in case of event delegation, you can achieve this by removing the class of the elements, or adding a second class and check for that. If the events are still bound directly to the elements: `detatchEvent()` and `removeEventListener()` will do, if you used `attachEvent` and `addEventListener`. otherwise: `el.onclick = null;` should work.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I'm assuming you down voted this answer: I do urge you [to check the JQ's source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) and just look at how many times events are delegated using code similar to this.

Comment: Hi Elias, I really appreciate your help. What parameters, and their order, should be sent as arguments, in the functions detatchEvent() and removeEventListener() ? Also, where to call them?

Comment: The same arguments as when you attached/detached the events. check: [detachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536411(v=vs.85).aspx) & [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13252/discussion-between-guy-david-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Comment: It's far too broad to say that this is how libraries work behind the scenes. This is how they work when performing event delegation, but they also do direct binding to elements. Also, this will break if the targeted element has nested elements that are clicked. It becomes more complex in real world situations.

Comment: When binding on a class selector, or binding multiple events, jQuery delegates. That's all I'm saying. I am currently chatting with the OP, and yes, he's got nested elements all over the place. I hinted at that by posting the link to QM's page on propagation/bubbling of events, which is, btw not that hard to deal with

Comment: className isn't compatible with IE 7 man :) use getAttribute('class') instead in case className not found

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: jQuery doesn't use event delegation when binding on a class, or when binding multiple events. It only uses event delegation when you use a delegation form of a method, like `.live()`, `.delegate()` or `.on()` *(only when a selector is provided)*. Otherwise if you simply do `$('.foo').on('click', my_func)`, there's no delegation. *(Though there could be some narrow uses that deal with specific browser fixes. These would be exceptions if so.)*

Comment: @Marwan: `.className` works fine in IE 6,7,8,9, because Elias is using the property name. *`properties !== attributes`* Anyway `getAttribute("class")` doesn't work in IE 6,7. You need `getAttribute("className")`. Unfortunately, the opposite is true for IE8.