# What happens to the event handler?

Tags: javascript, html

Example: A table with 1 row and 1 cell. Javascript gives this one cell and event handler which will append new rows.

```
<table border=1>
    <tbody id="target">
        <tr>
            <td class="hi" >I append</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


var els = document.getElementsByClassName("hi");
for(i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    els[i].onclick = function(){callMe(this)};
}

function callMe(t){
    var el = document.getElementById("target");
    el.innerHTML += '<tr><td class="hi" >appended...</td></tr>';
}
```

The `callMe` function gets called once, a new row is appended, the old row stays the same(I suppose). 
The second time the first cell is clicked the function does not get called. Why?
What happened there?
What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/2U3m3/1/

I am not using any libraries, just plain JavaScript. I want the first cell to be clickable always. It is meant to add rows forever not just one.

Comment: What do you want `this` that you are passing to `callMe()` point to? and why you are not using the variable `t` in the function? Please elaborate what should be the behavior you are looking for and whether you are using any libraries.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, `this` is used later on in my application, I didnt put that part in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The second time the first cell is clicked the function does not get called. Why?

Because overwriting the `innerHTML` of an element re-recreates all child elements, no matter if you just “append” to the innerHTML using `+=`.

And that the table cell has gotten replaced by a new one means that the event handler bound to the *old* table cell is also gone.

> The callMe function gets called once, a new row is appended, the old row stays the same(I suppose).

You “suppose” wrong here.

Comment: And can you tell me is there any other way to make it work without using obtrusive JS

Comment: @Dharman just bind the function to the click event after you append the line (inside the callMe function), should work.

Comment: Accepted because you gave the explanation of the problem but Ramy has provided a solution

Comment: As for the documentation you asked for, I can give you f.e. this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML: _“`element.innerHTML = content;` – Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.”_

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DOM methods for row/cell insertions if you plan to keep original event:

```
function callMe(t){
    var el = document.getElementById("target");
    var row = el.insertRow(el.rows.length);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0)
    cell.innerHTML = "Hi"
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/2U3m3/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the event to the class name directly. So any element with that class will have the click event including newly created ones. Adapted from the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273760/javascript-attach-event-to-class-name).

```
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click',clickHandler,false);
} else {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick',clickHandler); //for IE
}

function clickHandler(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className.match(/hi/)) //or whatever classname you want
    {
        callMe(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not what I was expecting but works like a charm. Thanks